# Clicking on an element is triggering all the same class instead of the one clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a sort-of popup menu that is specific to each `.smallCatalogBlock` div. The circle you see under the title is the trigger. The issue I am having is that if you click on the blue circle, both popup menus fadeIn, when it should only be that specific one.

The same applies to the popup title. It uses only the first `.smallCatalogBlock` information, opposed to the one clicked on.

Does anyone know how I can leave this in the dynamic setup I am going for, while populating the specific information for the one clicked on?

```js
var catalogName = $('.smallCatalogBlock').data('fill-specs');
//Filling Circle
$('.catalogSmallCircle').html(
  '<div class="catalogSmallCircleIn" data-catalog-name=' + catalogName + '><div class="total-center"><div class="circlePlus"></div></div></div><div class="catalogCircleExpand"><div class="catalogExpandClose">x</div><div class="total-center expandText"><span class="catalogName pdfSubHeader"></span><p class="dGw circleExpandText"></p><button class="catalogDownload downloadButton" name="Profile_Catalog" data-catalog-now="Profile Small Catalog Button" data-catalog-view-name="Profile Catalog">View</button><button class="catalogDownload requestButton" data-catalog-name="Profile Catalog">Request</button></div></div>'
)
//Circle Expand
$('.catalogSmallCircleIn').on('click', function() {
  //  old  $('.catalogSmallCircle').addClass('rectangle').find('.catalogSmallCircleIn').hide();
  $(this).closest('.catalogSmallCircle').addClass('rectangle').find('.catalogSmallCircleIn').hide();
  //  old  $('.catalogCircleExpand').fadeIn(100).addClass('rectangle');
  //$(this).closest('.catalogCircleExpand').fadeIn(100).addClass('rectangle');
  $('.catalogCircleExpand').fadeIn(100).addClass('rectangle');
  //Getting Catalog Name
  let catalogChoice = $(this).data('catalog-name');
  $('.catalogName').html(catalogChoice);
  event.stopPropagation();
});
//Close Circle
$('.catalogExpandClose').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.catalogSmallCircle').removeClass('rectangle').find('.catalogSmallCircleIn').fadeIn();
  $('.catalogCircleExpand').hide().removeClass('rectangle');
});
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.smallCatalogBlock {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.smallCatalogTitle {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.smallCatalogButtonWrap {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.catalogSmallCircle {
  background: #225DB8;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px auto;
  left: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.catalogSmallCircle.rectangle {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 2px solid #094765;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #225DB8, #4174C2);
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: auto;
}

.catalogSmallCircleIn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.circlePlus {
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.catalogCircleExpand {
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.catalogCircleExpand.rectangle {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-delay: .4s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.expandText .catalogDownload {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: .7em 1.1em;
}

.expandText .pdfSubHeader {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.catalogExpandClose {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogWrap">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-fill-specs="Catalog">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Catalog</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-fill-specs="Technology">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Technology</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think about it.  `$(selector)` is a global selector for the entire document.

Comment: You have to do a contextual lookup of some sort.  `$(selector, this)` or `$(this).find(selector)` are two versions of contextual lookups.

Comment: `$(this).closest(selectorForParentThatEncapsulatesUniqueGroupingOfElements).find(relatedElementWithinContext).doSomething()` would be another version of using contextual lookups

Comment: @Taplar This results in the same issue happening: `$('.catalogSmallCircleIn', this)`. I will try the other method.

Comment: Which click handler are you trying to fix first?  Keep in mind which elements you are binding on.  For instance, if you tried to do that in the Expand logic, your binding is on `catalogSmallCircleIn` so the `this` would already be one of those guys.  So if you tried to do that selector in that handler you'd be effectively looking for a circle in inside a circle in.  Not what you want in that case, eh?

Comment: @Taplar I got the part to work where only one rectangle appears, however the text for all the others is still appearing and the text in the box is not reflecting that box specific text. `$(this).closest('.catalogSmallCircle').addClass('rectangle').find('.catalogSmallCircleIn').hide();`

Comment: @Taplar I adjusted the code in my snippet.

Comment: Ok, now take a look at how you are getting the **single** value for `catalogName` and how you are setting **all** the `catalogSmallCircle` to have the same html.

Comment: @Taplar If I do the following, the value comes in as undefined. `var catalogName = $(this).closest('.smallCatalogBlock').data('fill-specs');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the `smallCatalogBlock`s and build them individually, otherwise they will all have the same catalog name.  And then in your event handlers, you have to make all your selectors be contextual lookups.

I ran the modified code, and it appears to be building the circles correctly, however for some reason the text is not showing up on them, even though the text is there if you inspect the element.  Didn't figure that part out, but this should show you at least how to do the contextual logic and the looping to build the elements.

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function(index, catalogBlock){
  var catalogName = $(catalogBlock).data('fill-specs');
  console.log(catalogName);
  //Filling Circle
  $('.catalogSmallCircle', catalogBlock).html(
    '<div class="catalogSmallCircleIn" data-catalog-name='+ catalogName +'><div class="total-center"><div class="circlePlus"></div></div></div><div class="catalogCircleExpand"><div class="catalogExpandClose">x</div><div class="total-center expandText"><span class="catalogName pdfSubHeader"></span><p class="dGw circleExpandText"></p><button class="catalogDownload downloadButton" name="Profile_Catalog" data-catalog-now="Profile Small Catalog Button" data-catalog-view-name="Profile Catalog">View</button><button class="catalogDownload requestButton" data-catalog-name="Profile Catalog">Request</button></div></div>'
  )
});

//Circle Expand
$('.catalogSmallCircleIn').on('click', function(event) {
  var $smallCircle = $(this).closest('.catalogSmallCircle');
  
  $smallCircle
    .addClass('rectangle')
    .find('.catalogSmallCircleIn')
    .hide();
  
  $smallCircle
    .find('.catalogCircleExpand')
    .fadeIn(100)
    .addClass('rectangle');
    
  //Getting Catalog Name
  let catalogChoice = $(this).data('catalog-name');
  console.log(catalogChoice);
  $smallCircle.find('.catalogName').html(catalogChoice);
  event.stopPropagation();
});

//Close Circle
$('.catalogExpandClose').on('click', function(event) {
  var $smallCircle = $(this).closest('.catalogSmallCircle');

  $smallCircle
    .removeClass('rectangle')
    .find('.catalogSmallCircleIn')
    .fadeIn();
  
  $smallCircle
    .find('.catalogCircleExpand')
    .hide()
    .removeClass('rectangle');
});
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 60px 0;
}
.smallCatalogBlock {
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.smallCatalogTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.smallCatalogButtonWrap {
 margin-top: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.catalogSmallCircle {
 background: #225DB8;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px auto;
 left: 90%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
    webkit-transition: all 1s;transition: all 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.catalogSmallCircle.rectangle {
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 2px solid #094765;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#225DB8,#4174C2);
 width: 400px;
 min-height: 200px;
 webkit-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;transform: translate(-45%, -45%);-webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -45%);
 z-index: 1;
 cursor: auto;
}
.catalogSmallCircleIn {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.circlePlus {
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
.catalogCircleExpand {
 height: 0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.catalogCircleExpand.rectangle {
 opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.expandText .catalogDownload {
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 padding: .7em 1.1em;
}
.expandText .pdfSubHeader {
 font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.catalogExpandClose {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogWrap">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-fill-specs="Catalog">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Catalog</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-fill-specs="Technology">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Technology</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I can't seem to figure out why the text isn't showing either. It has something to do with this line though `$('.catalogCircleExpand', this).fadeIn(100).addClass('rectangle');`. When I use the original line for this (without `,this`) the text shows, but it also pulls the other rectangles' text.

Comment: Fixed it, it was because the expand didn't belong to the element that was clicked.  @Paul

Comment: I am stumped on this title and now more than one expanded rectangle can be opened at once. I know why the title isn't showing. It is because nothing is populating it anymore. After the .html functinon in "Filling the Circle" section, I added this: `$('.catalogName').text(catalogName);`. Which shows the title, but not the right one again.

Comment: Because that's a global selector again, :)  You can't do that man if you have multiple elements with the same class.  You have to use a contextual lookup

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  You have a box per button.  Why would you need to "reset" their text?  It shouldn't be changing?  @Paul

Comment: I am resetting it when you close the "Request Catalog" popup, so that if the user clicks on a different option, the correct text would populate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183322/discussion-between-taplar-and-paul).

Comment: The SO chat doesn't open on my work computer. It is blocked for some reason.

Comment: @Paul ah, ok, well I changed the line to `$smallCircle.find('.catalogName').html(catalogChoice);` as the catalogName does not belong to the SmallCircleIn, it's in the Expand part, so you have to find it in the circle.

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you have any idea why when clicking on that "Request" button why the title on the left side always says "Profile Catalog" and never the fastening option? mbkit.com/catalogs

Comment: @Paul Depends on where that value is coming from.  However taking a quick look at the Request buttons, they all have the same `data-catalog-name`.  Also, while I'm happy to help, if you have further issues i would ask that you open a new question.

Comment: That was it. Thanks again!